# Are the chicks and devils that appear on character's heads an allegory for their state of mind?

Tags: okusama-ga-seitokaichou

In the manga and the anime series, sometimes a devil pops up from Izumi's head, and chickens from Wakana's head.

Izumi's devils seem an obvious allegory for the effects of

> Sexual arousal on his private parts

But I am not sure about Wakana Ui's chickens.

Are those devils and chickens an allegory for their mental state? What is the meaning of Wakana Ui's chickens?